# What to do with italian soda type syrups?

Tags: italian-cuisine, culinary-uses, syrup

I go to an Italian grocery store near my house that has an aisle filled with different flavors of syrup. I know you can make Italian soda by mixing it with carbonated water but I was wondering what other things you can make with them?

Comment: I have voted to close this as it is guaranteed to be subjective and argumentative. It is fundamentally no different than the many other "I have X, what can I do with it" questions we close every day.

Comment: thanks for your question! Please note that questions calling for a list of answers (as opposed to seeking a single "right" answer) should be started as Community Wiki. I've converted the question for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any kind of flavoring, really, so long as the application will accept a syrup substance.  They make killer milkshakes / malts.  Add them to all kinds of desserts, beverages.

I've occasionally replaced extracts and granulated sugar in a recipe with a flavored syrup but you  have to experiment with the right combinations as this tends to either overpower the dish with flavor or not make it as sweet.

Comment: The milkshakes/malt idea sounds awesome.. how do you make them?

Comment: @Kyra: they are quite good!  Just an ounce or so of syrup to a standard milkshake.  I used a shot of Peppermint syrup in a std vanilla milkshake with a couple drops of green food coloring to make Shamrock Shakes for St. Patrick's Day, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Coffee flavoring; Pouring it over Ice Cream; Mixing it with Cottage Cheese as a snack;

Comment: The cottage cheese idea sounds great. What flavors have you tried and like?

Answer (score 1):

I always enjoyed using them in vanilla ice cream milkshakes! Coconut is divine!

Answer (score 1):

To dress up hot chocolate. I particularly like raspberry and orange for this purpose, but many of them compliment chocolate nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Italian but I had to search "Italian soda" with Google to understand what you are talking about.

In fact Wikipedia, English edition, [rightly says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_sodaBlockquote):

> In spite of its name, Italian sodas originated in the United States, not Italy.

Comment: more of a comment, don't you think?

Comment: @justkt: yes, but as comment would pass unnoticed and I think that some people care about these "details".